# OAuth Flow not working when using Promise

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, oauth, promise

I am building a simple chrome extension which integrates with Twitter using OAuth. I have slightly modified the [Chrome OAuth Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth) to integrate with Twitter. The extension is build in Reactjs+Flux.

When the user clicks on "Sign in with Twitter" button, an Action signin is triggered, which is declared as follows:

```
signin: function(){
    ChromeUtils.connecttotwitter().then(alert("Step After Then"));       
    AppDispatcher.dispatch({actionType:TweetSmartActions.SIGN_IN,signedInTwitterUserId: response.user_id});
},
```

The ChromeUtils.connecttotwitter() is defined as follows:

```
var ChromeUtils = {

    connecttotwitter: function () {

        return new Promise(function(fulfill,reject){
            var request = {
                type : "background.twitterRequestToken",
            };
            alert("Before sendMessage");
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage(request, function(response) {

                if (response)
                {
                    fulfill(response);
                }
                else
                {
                    reject(response);
                }
            });
        });
    },
```

And the event listener onMessage is defined in the background.js as:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {

    console.log("background.js: " + JSON.stringify(request));

    var type = request.type;


    if (type == "background.twitterRequestToken")
    {
        oauth.authorize(function(token,secret,userId,screenname){
            sendResponse({success:true,userId:userId,screenName:screenname});
        });
        alert("Alerting before returning true");
        return true;
    }
```

When I click on the "Sign In With Twitter" button, the authentication flow does start and a new page opens. However, after I introduced the Promise, the new page does not redirect to the twitter oauth page. In fact, to debug that I have put the following alert statements in chrome_ex_oauth.js:

```
ChromeExOAuth.prototype.initOAuthFlow = function(callback) {
  if (!this.hasToken()) {
    var params = ChromeExOAuth.getQueryStringParams();
    if (params['chromeexoauthcallback'] == 'true') {
      var oauth_token = params['oauth_token'];
      var oauth_verifier = params['oauth_verifier']
      this.getAccessToken(oauth_token, oauth_verifier, callback);
    } else {
      var request_params = {
        'url_callback_param' : 'chromeexoauthcallback'
      }
      this.getRequestToken(function(url) {
        alert("Url after get request token " + url);
        window.location.href = url;
        alert(window.location.href);
      }, request_params);
    }
```

Here, the url in the first alert is the twitter oauth url but the second alert gives the Chrome extension Url -

```
chrome-extension://kiekipigbdldhggmlohbnhofnjhcbmem/chrome_ex_oauth.html
```

Why did the url not get assigned to window.location.href?

Any ideas on what might be happening?

Comment: `.then()` accepts a function *object* whereas `alert("....")` in your `signin:` is a function *call*, should be something like `.then(alert.bind(null,"...."))`

Comment: Ah, changed that and tested, but the execution never reaches then. It hangs because the window.location.href does not seem to get assigned.

Comment: no it runs in the background and is loaded in the manifest as follows   "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "chrome_ex_oauth.js",
      "chrome_ex_oauthsimple.js",
      "background.js"
    ],

Comment: So `chrome_ex_oauth.js` is a background script too. The `window` object refers to the background page window, not the active tab window. You should use `chrome.tabs.update` method or `chrome.tabs.executeScript` then to modify the active tab url.

Comment: I'll try that. But its intruiging because this is from the sample Google has provided for Oauth in Extensions and before I introduced the promise, the page used to go the twitter oauth url with the same code which had window.location.href. But let me try out your suggestion.

Comment: Well, the original code was written 3-5 years ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not because I was using a Promise, but because when using Flux, the Action was being Dispatched before the response from the Promise was received and this was causing the app to hang somehow

```
signin: function(){
    ChromeUtils.connecttotwitter().then(alert("Step After Then"));       
    AppDispatcher.dispatch({actionType:TweetSmartActions.SIGN_IN,signedInTwitterUserId: response.user_id});
},
```

In the above, the AppDispatcher.dispatch should be called in the function which is invoked on then.